# How does Inner join 3 or more tables works?

Tags: sql, inner-join

I saw some questions about the subject, but frankly i didn't quite understood.

What i want: I have five tables and i want to return a select with all intersections of the main table with the other 4. I'm currently doing 2 selects and then a UNION. It works great, but i guess i could improve the performance doing in a single select.

Here is an example of my code:

```
SELECT column1 FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN table B ON A.column1 = B.column1
LEFT JOIN table D ON A.column1 = D.column1
LEFT JOIN table E A.column1 = E.column1
WHERE B.column2 IS NOT NULL
AND B.column3 = '7'
AND ( (D.column2 = 'x' OR D.column3 = 'y') OR (E.column2 = 'x' OR E.column3 = 'y') )

UNION

SELECT column1 FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN table C ON A.column1 = C.column1
LEFT JOIN table D ON A.column1 = D.column1
LEFT JOIN table E A.column1 = E.column1
WHERE C.column2 IS NOT NULL
AND C.column3 = '7'
AND ( (D.otherColumn2= 'x' OR D.otherColumn3 = 'y') OR (E.otherColumn2 = 'x' OR E.otherColumn3 = 'y') )
```

About the tables.

Table **A** have the `column1` shared with all the other tables:

```
(int) column1
```

Tables **B** and **C** have the same structure as follows:

```
(int) column1 | (int) column2 | (varchar) column3
```

And tables **D** and **E** also have the same structure:

```
(int) column1 | (varchar) otherColumn2 | (varchar) otherColumn3
```

As we can see, both selects are pretty much the same, with the exception of the table **B** and **C**.

I asked this question without the full code and @Kevin solved it. But with this extra information, and trying to follow his example, i changed the code to:

```
SELECT column1 FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN table B ON (A.column1 = B.column1
    AND C.column2 IS NOT NULL
    AND C.column3 = '7')
LEFT JOIN table C ON (A.column1 = C.column1
    AND C.column2 IS NOT NULL
    AND C.column3 = '7')
LEFT JOIN table D ON A.column1 = D.column1
    AND (D.otherColumn2 = 'x' OR D.otherColumn3 = 'y')
LEFT JOIN table E A.column1 = E.column1
    AND (E.otherColumn2 = 'x' OR E.otherColumn3 = 'y')
WHERE
    B.column1 is not null
    or c.column1 is not null
    or D.column1 is not null
    or E.column1 is not null
```

But i getting a lot of extra results. I hope i'm making myself clear here, and if not, let me know and i will update this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you want.  However, I don't know that performance will be any better.

```
SELECT A.column1 FROM tableA A
    LEFT JOIN tableB B ON A.column1 = B.column1
        AND B.column2 IS NOT NULL
        AND B.column3 = '7' 
    LEFT JOIN tableD d ON b.column1 = D.column1
    LEFT JOIN tableE e ON B.column1 = E.column1
    LEFT JOIN tableC C ON A.column1 = C.column1
        AND C.column2 IS NOT NULL
        AND C.column3 = '7'
    LEFT JOIN tableD d2 ON c.column1 = d2.column1
    LEFT JOIN tableE e2 ON c.column1 = e2.column1
    WHERE (B.column1 is not null 
           and (d.othercolumn2 = 'x' or d.othercolumn3='y' or e.othercolumn2 = 'x' or e.othercolumn3='y')
           )
           or (c.column1 is not null
               and (d2.othercolumn2 = 'x' or d2.othercolumn3='y' or e2.othercolumn2 = 'x' or e2.othercolumn3='y')
           )
```

You can check it on [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fabe3f/4/0)

Comment: LEFT JOIN  adds results belonging just to A. Still not i what i'm trying to achieve, but thanks.

Comment: @Clyff yes, but the where clause excludes them. Did you try actually running the query as I wrote it? If you are trying to get results that are in tableB or tableC but not in both and are joining on the same column,  you will have to use a left join.

Comment: Just did it with the where clause, And its coming more restuls that was espected. I'm not familiar with join, but you sure i need to check `column1` is `not null`?

Comment: @Clyff check the sqlfiddle link I just added

Comment: Your code does what i asked before, thank you! But i'm afraid i omitted a important part of sql code and this change is affecting it too (again, i'm not familiar with joins, sorry). I updated the question

Comment: Try my new answer @clyff

Comment: Thanks for the help again @kevin! I made i check here and, as you suggested, the performance actually gets worse (4x or more). But again, that is what i asked for.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `exists`:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
where exists (select 1 from tableb b where a.column1 = b.column1 and b.column3 = 7) or
      exists (select 1 from tablec c where a.column1 = c.column1 and c.column3 = 7);
```

When you use `join`, you run the risk of getting duplicate rows -- and then you might do extra work to remove the duplicates.  All unnecessary with `exists`.

And, for performance, you want indexes on `tableb(column1, column3)` and `tablec(column1, column3)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i updated the question now. I tried to use this logic, but i can't do with the extra tables. i'm getting unexpected results.

Comment: Ok i did it. Turns out this query also is not as fast as the original with UNION (2-3x faster) . But again, thanks for sharing that knowledge and letting me know this wasn't an issue.

Comment: @Clyff . . . Even with the indexes, this is not as fast?

Comment: I can't change the database, so i cant check this.

Comment: @Clyff . . . With the appropriate indexes, I would expect this to be the fastest solution, so I wanted to check.